# Type safe pipe implementation in Typescript - inference issue

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm encountering a peculiar problem with Typescript inference.

I'm currently developing a `pipe` function, which takes a series of actions where each subsequent action relies on the result of the previous one.
Additionally, I'm creating a collection of auxiliary actions such as `first`, which selects the first item from the array.
Here is a stripped down code sample:

```js
function pipe<T>(x: T[], fn: ((a: T[]) => T) | T):T {
    if (typeof fn === 'function') return fn(x);
    return fn;
}
function first<T extends any[]>(x: T):T[0] {
    return x[0];
}
const result1 = pipe(["s", "t"], first);
//    ^? any
const result2 = pipe(["s", "t"], (x) => x[0]);
//    ^? string
```

In this particular scenario, we expect the `result1` to be a `string` but it's `any`. It's not an issue with result2 though.

I don't know what is the problem.
Can someone tell me what am I missing?

The full blown code is quite big and I have it here: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#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-PkwAAWGjwADobSkbY7sjCYXIQlZrlA+B1wgmosVKH8xKbEiZIgJcnA2njmgzgGY4AB+URwBgtq43RIVT6EPgmRDkUdinhuceTtuWSaFIgM5rrgCqy6rdNrMHrkWix43VqyreuCUsl8b+6PJ701fPL+v5And7HLc4AABVsAlc10N8oDgAA1D8vzrCJGzg28+WIOptUCJRK1UNosAAeQwGAwCIwh8PsaVxU0YwzDI7sfzI0gSlhLDgnoNQ8IASRMEiYAARkITiKIAbU-M9EIbaIhIAXQOJocK4niiIAJkE7gACkRLEmsJKvQTSFiBCLyQ6JNNknV5PY3D2m43iAGY1LgdTuAAaS0oyGKEwzxOMyTCE07ydN8vS3PM1jgQ4mylJgAAWRznLgFzuAAGXcnzPIM08goYgKsu-EzCDcwL8r81KwvhNiVGsrBbKIgBWeLXJS7gAFk0uygqvLy3TG1y7SSpCzL+p66JUuKkbCDa8rdQUqLeIANkaxLmrgFruAAOXagbGy64bgt6oaPIKoruv20bDvSgq2vGs7CE26bLKqxTeIAdiWpK4GS1qNu4ciUlEo6-N2wG9L6kHGxOvaGLG06GOu2GCs2m6GPI8zMIqiLrMEqcnzgBdEGE6Tfoo-p+gZXimE47kKHIfDuTyfC6nC2aAAZGJSUnqdp+m4EZuTsKstoBM44mObJ6KmGq2r+P0rneZ5vmLIFp6TFUkWnNFqhSfJojJeelT4tIOW6e7RXmcFkwHPVhKPr+rXxYpyKauiq2NNco3KG502mYx2a4utprPs1uBtYlp3pf9t3ls+j2afl730Zm9jgI0FBgL4GsCTwAS7bgYTrLZ1GfaTlQU7TjO+Cz1SpWD-O2jZqVMusgSa950hpOLx7UDL4B08zvAHNbgAhWuC8IRvuGb8fuCHpu2lUkfpWJjv+cq7vU97ius7i4fuAAYVH+vx7nkwW5nk+F+4Vu95PhyD7gRfW6L1eIp7vvK7wBrd7ge+ABFD5MA3E+Z8H4X0II-fet9CD3wgXAX+J84r-x-jPK+y8MJK3gAaRA7QWh4VOD0NEKBj79DzKQgA+kwN+W9s7HzeKBCA4E8C6AYlDAqjcmKdyUFgnBiJ8FwEIboYejxSF5goSBDe78q7T1AXQsCEFCAsPBtEWeHCX7cKwLgk4yJ+Eb2kYvG+JDyGUIkdQweKCf5G0oXIphCiCqsL8jfVRGC8Z4GwRo3h2iBF6P3tweBhjRHGPLv3He5i-6WJAtY5hdilGEHgU48K6jNFIjOF47+f9YjCKMeIoJH8v6hN8Rk2RDD5GKMun5b48SMaJI8Skje4sNAwD1oA+ci5MoiOaC6JpLSCZEzxq0wm3JLROm6LSOADS8BMHxoTf6K8AICAFGMmAJYsh0kQLGOMWQGkpD4FRLZpMQgQGaGMkwWyKBnJYDUkwzBuSjgZA0-o3ImB3JgOmACfINBHLJjAPMlYzlUAAEQQigP87kAIhSLOWXGD5IcGk-PYn8ns5hgD9jFGYUYGYNmLJSOwL56K3nZHGXmNoeAczNBgF8vMWxgCvL5OIRUfAYBYCzCHal6yNlguFDYJ4LjzRQBpaWP4zRIT9GdKMjpvQjkdLwIMjFKyoBrKGZi958AqA7OoiHfoBzJU9ARcwS51yRwtBMF86V44jX8qVZsz5sLfnnMBd4EF-JBQ9AaZCpV0KKW2qoL2ZFA40Wystac3obBcUBuVfmYlpLyWwqpRauMdKsAMqZSymV+L2UCkBCKVABpeVxtpX8GEfIOUQuhInJolyWgaCgLSUUEAYCqAgL2FqLJbRRlTUWjN4KK2EAAFo4zNMJKZvSRH42ko8HWjS4A9reAxHtwkWbSWEh2AkAAjNwY62VxlFfAQdNhpIpAnW6glnyM5QDzPMxk2ZKDnJZrkPIp7537oRT6lFg48WWuyMW1E6JvAKhtEwf5618LEDIaofCh51q-3+WGCMcATB1obU2ltXIj0LE7T0HFD6F1xrLNqapeDtF4n1IgQcAwQBMAeZ7UQhIJlwYwKutw7bP3obgxKCJxSbFkFJjoPAEABBrjlkwmAxANBEkbeSyjcdFXpt4-x4A-QQAPJwzRjUWpYTbv5JJPi2zdnwAEf0f5IBoN-AAPQmbjAAPWHH8fowkQDSTlnZomNnhKIG4PZuWRG+AkbMJzKjbm4B8RZizUYnAXMAC9uABY81R4SIjItwH+Su-5zmAJmas4KqtNb-nwaOI28wIK5B4rkBpnjV5lI6fVfpwzxm0vmb5BlgCtmYtxyc2Fprrn3MOao15nzfm44BaCyF9rfJbMJei911r8XuBJZSyN7I6XrMdfCwl8bXW5b9mreSnLdaWj5bMCCsbq2ovrfm1kRbRWgA).

---

I have oversimplified the code a little and the idea from @jcalz does not translate fully to my issue.
this is a more apropriate snippet:

```js
function pipe<A, B>(x: A, fn1: ((a: [A]) => B) | B): B {
    return null as B;
}
function first<T>(x: [T[]]): T {
    return x[0][0];
}

const result1 = pipe(["s", "t"], first);
//    ^? const result1: unknown
const result2 = pipe(["s", "t"], (x) => first(x));
//    ^? const result2: string
```

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Please [edit] to put the full example code here as plaintext; a link to an external IDE is a nice supplement but does not suffice to be a [mre].  Note that if the full example is "quite big" then it could be that your issue has too much code to be a good fit for SO. Ideally you'd work on whittling it down to a truly minimal and complete example.  Good luck!

Comment: TS can't do higher order generic type manipulation here; we could try to block inference of `T` from the second argument, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mblOow) shows. Does that meet your needs or am I missing something?

Comment: thanks @jcalz, I was trying to get my head around my full solution and I couldn't find the issue. 
In this sample code I think I see it. The problem is when the `fn` parameter of the `pipe` is either `(a: T[]) => T` or just a `T`. Allowing to provide just `T` makes it fail to infer the types correctly.
Now I wonder if I really need that in my solution. 
Nevertheless someone might find a solution for that useful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here; should I write up an answer or not?

Comment: Your solution seams to be fixing the issue. 
I'm not sure how, but it works.

Comment: I think I’m done here; the right time for updating the code example was before I wrote my answer, which was why I asked for confirmation before I did so. Oh well! Maybe someone else will come along to help further. Good luck!

Comment: Sure, thanx @jcalz. 
Your answer put me on the track. I'll dig deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue with your example code is that when you call `pipe()`, TypeScript can't properly infer `T` from the `fn` input when that function is itself a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function.  TypeScript lacks the kind of full type inference algorithm for generic [type unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) that would let it "plug in" the right generic type argument of `fn`.  This is a general limitation of TypeScript, described at [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134).  For now, any code that relies on higher-order generic type manipulation will probably fail without user intervention, such as manually [instantiating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) the relevant inner type argument:

```
const result1 = pipe(["s", "t"], first<string[]>); 
//    ^?const result1: string    //   ^^^^^^^^^^ <- instantiate
```

---

Depending on your use case, you might work around this by changing what the compiler uses to infer `T`. The existing `pipe()` function has a "higher priority" *inference site* for `T` at `fn`.  If the compiler tried first to infer `T` from the `x` input, then it would behave better, since `["s", "t"]` is clearly of type `string[]` without any generic function instantiation issues to break things.

It would be nice if we could say "hey, please infer `T` from `x` and not from `fn`"  That is, we'd like to maybe mark the `T` occurrences inside `fn` as a *non-inferential type parameter usage*.  Maybe that would be

```
declare function pipe<T>(x: T[], fn: NoInfer<((a: T[]) => T) | T>): T;
```

There's an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  Currently the language doesn't directly provide `NoInfer<T>`, but the issue describes various approaches to simulate or emulate it.

One thing we can do is add a second type parameter `U` and [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) it to the first type parameter `T`.  Then we use `U` as a "non-inferential" version of `T`.  That works because `T` and `U` will be inferred separately, and the compiler will check `U` against `T`.

For `pipe()` that could be:

```
function pipe<T, U extends T>(x: T[], fn: (((a: U[]) => U) | U)): T {
    if (typeof fn === 'function') return (fn as (a: T[]) => T)(x);
    return fn;
}
```

Now when we call it, things behave as desired:

```
const result1 = pipe(["s", "t"], first);
//    ^? const result1: string
```

If you check, you'll see that `T` is inferred as `string` from `["s", "t"]`, and then `U` is also `string`.  Probably `U` was first inferred as `unknown` as before, but then that failed and it fell back to the constraint of `T`, which was `string`, and thus `first` is checked against `(a: string[]) => string)` and it succeeds.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJEpAMwFdh4AXDAe2CRgxggB4AVAPgAoAPAFxJOAbQC6AGnLBhvXiGFjxASiQBebiLUAfbUrxFSxpBjJJeNAJ5t65sk3VOkAckrU6jF2rQQaFNCZeByQQKAtFEQk1TW0BFQBuIxMSX39AmSTiUgBfZJJ3WgYmMgw0KBouJAh+GghgABNwkGArCT4hfSiABnFDbJS0gKZ+UV6s4zyBpHhGCqRfKAoAGxoARg1mVgheUQAiKD3pPZo9qXIyivYKzGAsdsT8pAB6Z+MAPQB+WeB5xZX1sIbhg7kQiFMiIVPEwWGwuNIAKrVWr1JoiDpKCTSBxyeSRBHRDRaBG6JAklQGAjTMwWay2eyOZxuKhFLw+PzDCwhMIRTGqIlxfiPaZDDIOLIQwhQ4oXcqVTjIuqNcJUADWwHoAHdgO0BEoKT0+lTjKKRmNxBKiD8-tAARt1Fs2LsDkckCcztjLjRha8Pp8ZnMaAtbas1kCaLcsGDCNag-9VgAmTawnb7Q7HU7neIC0a9H1vUhfIhAA)